# How to create slide out menu without the view updating

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7

Hi I'm currently developing an app with a slide out menu. Im using SWRevealController to handle the menu and such. But in one of the views the you push from the tableview menu that slides out i have a webView. And my question is can you with SWRevealController do so that the viewControllers remain in the navigation stack and don't have to reload every time you click to the view? Or do i have to use some other like MMDrawerController or MFSlideMenu?
Thanks.

Comment: Create a parent view controller and add your other view controller's as children to the parent, that way they'll be in the stack.

Comment: Ok so is it just to create a new viewcontroller.h and .m and then what?

Comment: I can't remember how SWReveal works internally, as I've pretty much decided to create whatever I need over the years. What I do when I want everything contained, I create a ViewController as the holder for the other view controllers, then I add those view controller's views as subviews to the parent. This works great if you don't have complex or alot of views in memory.

Comment: Did you have any luck with this one? I'm curious to see if you managed to resolve this issue.